# LaunchDaemon handling system shutdown - no SIGTERM?

Tags: python, macos, launchd

I've written a small python script that I'm running as a LaunchDaemon to record startup/shutdown times to a remote database. When the script launches it records the startup time, then pauses and waits to catch SIGTERM to record the shutdown time. An almost identical workflow is being used as a LaunchAgent for login/logout times.

However, it appears that Apple's Sudden Termination mechanism is throwing a wrench into things. It appears that when the machine is shutdown or restarted, `launchd` is only sending a `SIGKILL` signal to the launchdaemons and launchagents, which cannot be handled. I may be wrong in the technicalities, but that's essentially what I'm experiencing..

Manually loading/unloading the daemon with launchctl triggers the `SIGTERM` handler. However, that same code is not triggered when real system shutdown occurs.

Does anyone have a recommendation on how to prevent a `SIGKILL`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I'm reading [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/MacOSX/WhatsNewInOSX/Articles/MacOSX10_6.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008898-SW22) right, it shouldn't use sudden termination on daemons unless you have  `<key>EnableTransactions</key><true/>` in the launchd plist.  But the docs are a little vague, so I'd also try adding `<key>EnableTransactions</key><false/>` to the plist, or if that doesn't work call vproc_transaction_begin from your program (I assume you can call it from python, but I don't know the mechanics).

Comment: Wow... Adding `<key>EnableTransactions</key><false/>` did the trick. I was previously omitting it, assuming false was the default value. The process is now sent a signal 15 (SIGTERM) instead of a signal 9 (SIGKILL).

Comment: Yes. I thought about that as well, but I found no differences pertaining to EnableTransactions in the 10.6 and 10.7 launchd.plist man pages. Unfortunately now, after all this work, I find that the network has already been brought down by the time the signal handler fires off :)

Comment: Hi, I know it's been a while, but I'm dealing with the exact same situation in macOS Sierra and High Sierra.. perhaps do you know which flag disable the sudden termination of daemons ?